# Wcf integration task, need to transfer large amount of data via soap service

Tags: wcf, web-services, architecture, soap, soa

I have to design an integration solution that transfers large amount of data and works once a day. The company X we work with will invoke the service / services and give the data as parameters.

Do you have any suggestions for this solution?

For example do you think that I have to tell the company X that they have to send compressed (gzip?) data?

Or do I have to realise this usage scenario:

```
while(!allDataSent)
{
    SendData(List<object> objects);
}    
TransferCompleted();
```

How do you develop this kind of tasks?

Comment: Do you know what kind of data will be sent? Is this a file transfer?

Comment: The objects will not be able to be arbitrary. The service will need to know their types in order to deserialize them.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to have separate endpoints for the service and client that are going to do the data transfer because you need to change the timeouts and maximum limits for how much data you can send and receive within the connection. If it's not time critical you can use `IEnumerable<YourType>` as the return type for the function and on the client end, they can use it as a stream and can batch save it while it's getting the data so that there won't be a need to have it all in memory.

On the clientside it could look something like this:

```
foreach (var bytes = servliceClient.GetLargeAmountOfData())
   SaveByteToDisc(bytes);
```

Information about the binding properties can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx)

Comment: Hmm... What do I have to google to understand how to achieve this?

Comment: Added some code to show how it could look on the client side. On the server side it's a quesion of request timeout values and that can be found in the MSDN documentation